# Nginx configuration SCRIPT_FILENAME

Tags: php, nginx, yii, url-rewriting, stderr

I have old configuration with apache. Now i want to reconfigurate everything to nginx+php-fpm. But have some problems with SCRIPT_FILENAME.
My project stores in folder /www. It have 3 folderis in it.

- 1st folder for static images. (img) Should work on site.com/images/[1.png]
- 2nd folder for custom php scripts (php) Sloud work on site.com/php/[qweqwe]
- 3rd foled for Yii project.(yii) Should work on site.com/yii/

They have custom rewrites.

Here my nginx server config:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name site.com;

  root /www;

  location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|swf|flv|eot|ttf|woff|pdf|xls|htc|html)$ {
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires   360d;
  }
  location /php {
    root /www/php;
    if (!-e $request_filename){
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /php/api2.php;
    }
    location ~* \.php$ {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   pool;
    }
  }

  location /yii {
    root /www/yii;
    rewrite (.*)\.small\.([^\.]+)$ /sfad/thumb.php?img=$1.$2 break;
    rewrite agent[0-9]+site[0-9]+[a-z]*/(.*) /$1;
    location ~* \.php$ {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   pool;
        }
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
  }
}
```

But every time i have error

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: I'm not certain but those nested location blocks seem like a bad idea.  If you haven't already done so, I recommend reading these [NGINX troubleshooting tips](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls).  This really helped me come up to speed on `NGINX`.  Also, you may want to create a very simple server block, verify that it works for one of your use cases and then expand from there.

Comment: Change document root to real path.  change this line ``fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`` to ``fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /www$fastcgi_script_name;``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already made it) With [help](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) Thanks steve klein.
My final config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site.com;


  access_log /var/log/nginx/olimpic-access.log main buffer=16k;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/olimpic-dev-error.log warn;
  root /www;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
  location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
  location ~ /.ht         { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location ~ /yii/(protected|framework|nbproject) { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found$
  location ~ /yii/themes/\w+/views { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|swf|flv|eot|ttf|woff|pdf|xls|htc|html)$ {
    rewrite (.*)\.small\.([^\.]+)$ /yii/sfad/thumb.php?img=$1.$2;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires   360d;
  }

  location ~* /yii/agent[0-9]+site[0-9]+[a-z]*/(.*) {
    rewrite agent[0-9]+site[0-9]+[a-z]*/(.*) /yii/$1;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /yii/index.php?$args;
  }

  location /yii/ {
    try_files $uri /yii/index.php?$args;
  }

  location /php/ {
    try_files $uri /php/api2.php;
  }

  location ~* \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/php/(.*)$ /php/api2.php break;
    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_pass   php-workers;
  }
}
```